# Spring-Boot application Class loading issue on JBOSS EAP

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-boot, jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly

I am trying to deploy a Spring-Boot application(war) on JBOSS EAP 6.4. The application works fine on Tomcat but in JBOSS getting below error:

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jpa" />
            <subsystem name="JAX-RS" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javaee.api" />
            <module name="javax.xml.bind.api" />
            <module name="javax.xml.bind.annotation.api" />
            <module name="javax.persistence.api" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javaee.api">
                <imports>
                    <exclude path="javax/persistence" />
                    <exclude path="javax/xml/bind" />
                    <exclude path="javax/xml/bind/annotation" />
                </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Error:

```
11:53:09,887 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 91) Failed to define class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs in Module "javax.xml.bind.api:main" from local module loader @5af1c8f4 (finder: local module finder @37c039d1 (roots: /dbidapp/jboss/modules,/dbidapp/jboss/modules/system/layers/base)): java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlNs"
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
```